# how to trim string variables in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have strings that initially contain different directory paths, where both the 2nd and 2nd last sub-directories can vary in length, like so

```
 /home/Leo/Work/CMI/ARCH/MWS/Disks
 /home/Cleo/Work/CMI/ARCH/BK/Disks
```

I want to trim the first 5 sub-directories and only show the last 2, like so

```
 echo "/MWS/Disks"
 echo "/BK/Disks"
```

One way to trim the first 5 sub-directories from the initial strings might be to left-shift each character until both strings start with the second last '/'.

The *[Bash Beginners Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html)* describes a `shift built-in` that left-shifts positional parameters in a command and throws away unused arguments. But it is not immediately obvious whether this could be used to trim the first 5 sub-directories from the strings described above.

In Bash, how do I reduce these strings, preferably without using loops ?

---

**CLARIFICATION**

Judging from comments a bit more context is needed. My Bash script recovers historic Mdos and Qdos files from 8-inch floppy disk images and saves files to directories on the hard drive.

For better or worse, I created a bespoke scheme that stores directory paths using 3-character variable names where each name is an acronym for the section of the path to the current directory.

For example `MWC` is an acronymn for `$MY/Work/CMI` in the following path

```
MY="$USER"
MWC="C:/cygwin64/home/$MY/Work/CMI"
cd "$MWC"
pwd
C:/cygwin64/home/$MY/Work/CMI
```

Similarly 3-character variables point to the next sub-directory further up the tree

```
WCA="$MWC/ARCH"
```

i.e. `C:/cygwin64/home/$MY/Work/CMI/ARCH`, path to a gallery of archive owners.

As directory paths lengthen the 3-character variables make paths easily identified by conserving white space in the listing. Nevertheless the full path appears whenever my script references a path. Hence the need to trim parts of the string that have no interest for the end user.

Comment: Do you have a possibility to use sed? ```echo /home/Leo/Work/CMI/ARCH/MWS/Disks | sed 's#^\(/[^/]*\)\{5\}##'```

Comment: yes though this example didn't work

Comment: I tried it  [online](https://replit.com/@DavidLukas1/AdorableBestIntercept#main.sh)

Comment: how are you processing this list of directories/files? are they coming from a file? a stream from a separate OS process? one-by-one via a variable (eg, in a loop)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the number of subdirectories is always the same, you can use parameter expansion to remove the first 5 subdirectories:

```bash
s=/home/Leo/Work/CMI/ARCH/MWS/Disks
s=/${s#/*/*/*/*/*/}
echo $s  # /MWS/Disks
```

Or, if you know you need the last two parts whatever the depth of the path is:

```bash
s=/home/Leo/Work/CMI/ARCH/MWS/Disks
last=/${s##*/}
last_but1=${s%$last}
last_but1=/${last_but1##*/}
echo $last_but1$last  # /MWS/Disks
```

- `${s#PATTERN}` removes PATTERN from the beginning of `$s`.
- `${s%PATTERN}` removes PATTERN form the end of `$s`.
- with `#` or `%`, the shortest match of PATTERN is found. Doubling them makes the match the longest possible.

Comment: the last two parts are needed so the user (named in the 2nd sub-directory) knows whose disk archive they are working on (i.e. the archive owner named in the 2nd last sub-directory) - if that makes sense.

Comment: @Greg: I rephrased the comments to explain what the difference between the two approaches is. Both of them would probably work for you.

Comment: This is good. I'm checking each. Do you have a reference on parameter expansion ?

Comment: `man bash` describes it a bit tersely, so experiment with it to understand the nuances :-)

Comment: You're dead right. It took a bit of experimentation to see how this answer addressed the question. There's no way I would have got there by reading man bash. The three bullet-points really helped.

Comment: @choroba: thanks from me too. Just that I think in your explanation you got meanings of `#PATTERN` and `%PATTERN` swapped over. Cheers.

Comment: @saulius2: Oops, you're right. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the parameter expansion, you can use the `=~` operator:

```
dir='/home/Leo/Work/CMI/ARCH/MWS/Disks'
[[ $dir =~ /[^/]*/[^/]*$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
```

Comment: I not sure what you changed but this worked both before and after the edit. Can you recommend a reference on the =~ operator ?

Comment: @Greg [Bash Reference Manual, Conditional constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs). Search for the `=~` in the page.

Comment: @Greg Also, [Regular Expressions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the inputs are coming from a file (or streamed/piped from another OS process) ...

Sample input:

```
$ cat dir.file
 /home/Leo/Work/CMI/ARCH/MWS/Disks
 /home/Cleo/Work/CMI/ARCH/BK/Disks
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="/"} {print OFS $(NF-1),$(NF)}' dir.file
```

This generates:

```
/MWS/Disks
/BK/Disks
```

---

If the results need to be stored for later use it shouldn't be too hard to add some code as needed (eg, redirect to a file, pipe to another process, pass as input to a `while/read` loop, load into an array, etc).

If OP is processing these strings one at a time (eg, as a variable in a loop), I'd probably stick with a parameter substitution solution (see choroba's answer) which doesn't require any overhead to spawn subprocesses.

Comment: See my edits. They answer your questions. Your awk solution is working but I'll confirm when I have tried this in my script

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin has `find` right?

So can you do:

```
cd 'C:/cygwin64/' # I guess?

find "/home/$USER/work/CMI/ARCH" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name Disks |
sed 's=/Disks$=='
```

Or this, to list all of them:

```
find /home/*/work/CMI/ARCH/*/ -type d -name Disks |
sed 's=/Disks$=='
```

If you just want to edit the string, you can use prefix removal:

```
$ path=/home/Leo/Work/CMI/ARCH/MWS/Disks
$ path=/${path#/*/*/*/*/*/*}
$ echo "$path"
/MWS/Disks
```